# He admitted that it took... Or, He admitted having it

Tags: grammar, verbs

Consider the following example:

A man wrote a book in 2 days. He admits it.

Should I say:

1. "He admitted that it took him 2 days to write the book"
2. "He admitted that it had taken him 2 days to write the book"
3. "He admitted having it taken 2 days to write the book"

Comment: The first two are fine, same meaning; narrator's choice. The third one is flat-out ungrammatical; I can't see where that construction came from; I've never heard anything like it.

Comment: Oh, I see the problem. You're not paying attention to extraposition. Try _He admitted having taken 2 days to write the book,_ which is (a) grammatical and (b) un-Extraposed (i.e, there's no inserted dummy _it_; the subject of _having taken_ is _He_).

Comment: @John: My first thought for "correcting" #3 was rather less radical. *"He admitted **it having** taken 2 days to write the book"* sounds fine to me, and only involves moving the position of ***it*** rather than deleting it. I could imagine a "deleted?" ***to*** before it, but both sound okay to me.

Comment: @JohnLawler thanks, I see the problem now. Can I use it in passive,  i.e. not in form "he took 2 days" but "2 days were taken from him". Can it be like this: "He admitted having been taken 2 days"?

Comment: @ Bait: That's not how I interpret figurative "take" here. He's *taking up the time* himself (his, but which might have been *given over* to other things instead), rather than having it taken *from* him [by the task].

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am wondering about this example. It was on my mind for a while and I don't know what's the best way to say what I mean. What would you say if you were in this example?

Comment: @ Bait: If I really had to choose "the best" of all four valid versions here (not your third one, but the two different ways of "salvaging" it), I'd probably go for John's as the shortest, most direct, and *probably* most common. But there's nothing wrong with any of them, so really it's pointless to ask which is "better".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number 3 would more idiomatically be "He admitted it having taken him 2 days to write the book."

(Apparently the system understood **#** as introducing a headline. Odd.)